# Which are arguments here?

Tags: clojure

I'm a really newbie at clojure. 
I have this

```
(defn max-val [x & xs]
  (reduce #(if (< %1 %2) %2 %1) (flatten (cons x xs))))
```

Which are the %1 and %2 arguments?
I understand that

```
(flatten (cons 1 2 3)
```

Will return a lazy-seq, making just one argument to the #() function

Comment: are you asking about how to use reduce? Or are you asking how to build anonymous functions using the #( ... % ... %1 ... %n ...) syntax?

Comment: `(cons 1 2 3)` doesn't return a lazy seq at all: it is an error to give more than 2 arguments to `cons`, or for the second argument to not be something sequential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at [the docs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce) for `reduce`

> `(reduce f coll) (reduce f val coll)`
>
> f should be a function of 2 arguments. If val is not supplied,
>   **returns the result of applying f to the first 2 items in coll, then
>   applying f to that result and the 3rd item, etc.** If coll contains no
>   items, f must accept no arguments as well, and reduce returns the
>   result of calling f with no arguments.  If coll has only 1 item, it
>   is returned and f is not called.  If val is supplied, returns the
>   result of applying f to val and the first item in coll, then
>   applying f to that result and the 2nd item, etc. If coll contains no
>   items, returns val and f is not called.

So it applies the function to the next item in the list, as well as the result of the previous invocation (the first time using the first two items in the list).

Imagine you call your function like this:

```
(reduce #(if (< %1 %2) %2 %1) '(1 2 3 4))
```

It will first be called with `1` and `2`, returning `2`. Then it will be called with the result, `2`, and the next item, `3`, and return `3`. Then it's called with the result, `3`, and the next item `4`, and returns `4` as the final result.

Each step uses the result of the previous invocation as the first argument for the next time.